# iOS7 UITableViewCell background transparancy becomes opaque after a short pause

Tags: uitableview, ios7, transparency

I have a UITableView which is presented modally over a view. One of the cells in the table view is deliberately transparent so that the view underneath is visable. The issue is that is IOS 7.1 the cell starts off transparent and then immediately becomes opaque. Under iOS 8 the transparent cell technique works perfectly.

Qn. Has anyone seen this and come up with a valid work-around?

**Things I've tried**

- Adjusting cell.backgroundColor
- Adjusting cell.backgroundView
- Adjusting tableView.backgroundColor
- Adjusting tableView.backgroundView
- Setting tableView.opaque = YES;
- Making the adjustments in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
- Making the adjustments in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
- Using full transparencies
- Using partial transparencies
- Using transparent images
- [[UITableViewCell appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Essentially as soon as any transparency is introduced into the background it changes (after a slight pause to become opaque).

[image]

To re-iterate under iOS7 the transparency is there very briefly (less than a 1/2 sec) then it turns opaque.

Here is a vimeo of the effect: [Link](https://vimeo.com/112792030)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than focusing on the tableview and it's cells, look at the presenting (bottom) view controller. I believe (although I can't find it officially documented at the moment) that when you do a standard modal presentation of one view controller over another, the presenting view controller's view is removed from the view hierarchy after presentation. Working with a trivial test app, the presenting view controller's -viewWillDisappear: is called and logging the key window's -recursiveDescription show the presenting view controller's view has been removed.

However, if you use a custom transition, the presenting view controller's view is kept in place (presumably to allow for exactly this kind of transparency effect).

EDIT: I've put together a quick example app (here: https://github.com/sjc/ViewControllerTransitionExample) to 1) illustrate the difference in behaviour between standard and custom modal presentation, and 2) to show how a basic UINavigationController subclass can be built to solve this issue (the technique is normally just applied to straight UIViewController subclasses).

However... While this can be used to solve the issue in this case, it doesn't answer the 'what's going on here?' question, since the example doesn't reproduce exactly what you are seeing: the presenting view controller disappears on both iOS 7 and 8, and not just on 7, as described in the original question. Oh well.

Comment: I've plumbed in your custom transition navigation controller to my app and it works! I don't know the answer as to why your example the 'Normal' transition fails for both iOS7 and iOS8. But you have solved my issue. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try to change to table cell from the **Appearance** system in your **AppDelegate**

```
[[UITableViewCell appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this now and it makes no difference. I will update the question with the fact this has been attempted.

Comment: Hi, I've created a very basic example http://youtu.be/3RbdyGYZcvI ,please confirm if this what you need. the table view has three cells and the first one in transparent.

Comment: Yes - but see @dasdom answer - it needs to work under iOS7 as well as iOS8

Comment: I'm sorry, I've forgot to upload IOS7 video http://youtu.be/TAxHtbM8LAA btw: I have faced your problem and it was because of cell height was too large

Answer (score 1):

This won't work on iOS 7 because modal views are always opaque. On iOS 8 they can be transparent.
You will have to find another solution on iOS 7.

That is seems to work for 1/2 of a second is because modal views aren't opaque during transition.

Comment: useful to know - "modal views aren't opaque during transition."